# Customize folder under Windows 7: Preview and filters must be enabled?

Tags: windows-7

When I customize a folder under Windows 7 (right-click, `Customize this folder...`) and change the `Optimize this folder for` selection I get a dialog that says:

> Preview and filters must be enabled to see your changes. Would you like to turn them on?

What does this mean, and if I say yes, what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is enabled by default in W7. Not sure how it got disabled.

This will enable advanced view settings while in folders. Not a bad thing. It just enables features and really does not change anything unless you change other view settings.

Comment: Company PC, perhaps they changed some settings.

Comment: I looked around and could find no users way to disable it, maybe they did it in group policy or other advanced setting buried in the OS or registry.